# Information regarding the files of a project in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am planning to develop a 2d game using directx and Xaml on Windows Phone 8 platform. I am able to create a new project in visual studio "windows phone xaml and direct2d" but Where can I find information regarding all the files of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct2D is not supported on Windows Phone 8. You can try use Direct3D with once one plane, but Direct3D is very hard, I'm not kidding! After a long time you can draw a simple triangle. You should try use XNA to build 2D games, it will be more productive for you.